# IOS 8 Location services anomaly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I see this is being asked here since the release of IOS 8 but I am not sure what to do.

My app worked OK in IOS 7. In IOS 8 the location services do not prompt user for authorization so I added the following:

myapp_info.plist

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
    My app needs location services

and in code:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

The app runs fine in the simulator (Xcode 6) and request location service permission.
If I run the app (from Xcode) on my device it also prompts and works properly.
If I create an Ad-Hoc build and install to my device via iTunes everything works.

If I download and install the same build from App Store it does not work. Does not prompt and does not attempt location services.

I am not really sure what to do next?

Comment: So the code you posted above exists in the app that has already been submitted/accepted on the app store?

Comment: Yes. It worked as described above.